# Another problem with display graphic

Tags: graphics, floats, placeins

I have full code of my document (I hope it's correct now):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins,listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Java, breaklines=true, basicstyle=\small, columns=fullflexible}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
Text 1
\\ Text 2:
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image1.jpg}
\caption{Caption 1} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image2.jpg}
\caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image3.jpg}
\caption{Caption 3} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image4.jpg}
\caption{Caption 4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image5.jpg}
\caption{Caption 5}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier

Text 3

\FloatBarrier

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics{image6.jpg}
\caption{Caption 6}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image7.jpg}
\caption{Caption 7}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image8.jpg}
\caption{Caption 8}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics{image9.jpg}
\caption{Caption 9}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And I get this: [page1](http://www.tinypic.pl/leq3s80blb18) - image6 is after Text3 and another pictures (image7, image8, image9) are on next page, not after image6 [page2](http://www.tinypic.pl/hx7tz0tksg1i).

Comment: Please edit your question so that your example is a _complete_ document that reproduces the error, you can use the `[demo]` option to `graphicx` so that it just uses rectangles, so you do not need to supply images in the example.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Your code will not compile as it stands and is certainly not minimal!

Comment: I would drop some of the `\begin{figure}...\end{figure} statements and just use `\includegraphics...` in order to keep the graphic where you want to have it. In this case use `\captionof{figure}{yourcaptiontext}` instead of `\caption...`, do not forget to `\usepackage{caption}` in the preamble

Comment: What's the issue? Your MWE (after fixing it up a bit...) provides space for only three figures per page; figure 6 happens to be at the bottom of page 2, and figures 7, 8, and 9 are on page 3. What do you want to change about this setup?

Comment: I want have figure6 and figure7 on one page, and figures8 and figure9 on second page

Comment: How large are those `image*.jpg` files? Do they have all the same dimensions?

Comment: Yes, they have the same size - 266x213

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I do not know the dimensions of the images and only demo mode of `graphicx` can be used, a trial solution, by removing the floating aspect of fig. 6 and 7 and combining fig. 8 and 9 into one float. The place where fig 8. and 9 do appear depends of course on text etc.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} % My addition
\usepackage{placeins}
%\usepackage{listings} % Not needed here!

\def\myscalingfactor{0.5} % Better for many images!

\begin{document}
%\lstset{language=Java, breaklines=true, basicstyle=\small, columns=fullflexible} % Not needed here
\tableofcontents
\clearpage % or \cleardoublepage if necessary is better in my point of view

\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
Text 1
\\ Text 2:
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=\myscalingfactor]{image1}
\caption{Caption 1} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=\myscalingfactor]{image2}
\caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=\myscalingfactor]{image3}
\caption{Caption 3} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=\myscalingfactor]{image4}
\caption{Caption 4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=\myscalingfactor]{image5}
\caption{Caption 5}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier

Text 3

%\FloatBarrier

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{image6}%
\captionof{figure}{Caption 6}%
\includegraphics{image7}%
\captionof{figure}{Caption 7}%
\end{center}%
\FloatBarrier
% Now floating pictures
\begin{figure}  % Combine two graphics in one figure...
\centering
\includegraphics{image8}
\caption{Caption 8}
\includegraphics{image9}
\caption{Caption 9}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]